# Div alignments one above another?

Tags: html, css

How would I achieve the below shown design using html and css?

[image]

The sidebar should be on top of all other items such as logo and menu and content. The menu should be behind wrap the sidebar. The content are is in 'L' shape. The content area should go up to sidebar and the come below the sidebar. The sidebar length is less than the total content area.

Comment: FYI: If you indent each line with four spaces, Markdown will render that line as code. This means that it will respect whitespace (and you won't have to drive yourself crazy with `&nbsp;`).

Comment: Do you have any code so far that you can post?

Comment: The raw design that i want to achieve (http://postimage.org/image/6ewdbhatj/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a good rough draft to get you started.

(http://jsfiddle.net/tech0925/Sm8HB/)

Cheers!

Comment: Here is the link to clarify my design.
[link] (http://postimage.org/image/6ewdbhatj/)

Comment: Working on it now for you :)

Comment: Here is a good rough draft to get you started. http://jsfiddle.net/tech0925/Sm8HB/ I'll update my answer above.

Comment: Is that what you needed? IF so consider choosing this as the best answer. Happy to help.

Comment: I want the mainContent to flow upto the sidebar (left to right) and then come in next line. 
Your code hides the mainContent behind the sidebar.
No content should be shown after the sidebar.
Thanks again.
As you can see the image I've uploaded the mainContent is in 'L' shape

Comment: There you go.. Please see the new fiddle revisions